# Emacs inside terminal change cursor color dynamically

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp

I'm trying to change the color of my cursor inside Emacs to another color dynamically.

I'm using `emacs -nw` for the terminal Emacs. The terminal I'm using is Rxvt-Unicode (Urxvt).

Since Emacs can't (I think) make changes to the terminal, `(set-cursor-color "red")` won't work. In order to change the cursor color of the terminal I can run 
`echo -ne '\033]12;red\007'`. This changes the color of the cursor to red.

What I tried to do in Emacs is to run this command inside it. 
`M-x shell-command RET echo -ne '\033]12;red\007' RET`

However, Emacs will escape the echoed string and print it at the bottom of the window, and not actually make any changes to the cursor.

I really don't know what else I can do from here, I don't want to use the Emacs GUI. Does anyone know a way around this? I want to be able to change the color of my cursor depending on my current mode, which is why it needs to be dynamic. If anyone has any other suggestions I would be happy to hear them!

Comment: `shell-command` runs the command in an inferior shell, so it won't take effect in the containing Emacs.  I don't know how to get Emacs to echo escape sequences directly ... I tried using (message ...) with the escape sequence in there but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `send-string-to-terminal`.

E.g. `(send-string-to-terminal "\033]12;red\007")`.

Comment: It seems that this is the best solution! Thanks a lot. Pains me to have to unaccept Francesco's answer, but this one works best. Still thanks both of you for your help!

Comment: Ok now I'm feeling silly :( even though I thought it worked (and it does) however whenever I run the function it prints the text in the editor itself. So this won't work I'm afraid. I'll leave this question unanswered for a little longer and otherwise I'll have to accept Francesco's answer again. My apologies..

Comment: This definitely seems like it is the right way to go. Yet I don't understand why it doesn't work as expected... (In my setup, it doesn't change the cursor color and prints the ANSI sequence in the terminal ; I have to run `M-x redraw-display` to get rid of it)

Comment: Works for me.  If you have been using double backslashes, they need to be single, of course (you are not sending stuff to the shell, but to Emacs itself).

Comment: You're right, it does work! I wrote it wrong. In the example it works perfectly :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: A small package which automatically synchronizes the frame cursor color (as you'd see it in graphical window systems) with xterm using this method: https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-cursor-color

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hackish solution -- I hope someone will find a better one:

```
(suspend-emacs "echo -ne '\\033]12;red\\007'; fg\n")
```

It works by temporarily suspending the emacs process and stuffing commands into the underlying terminal to make the shell change the cursor color and resume emacs after that. However, this causes the screen to flicker while the emacs frame temporarily disappears.

---

Here is another very hackish and system-dependent solution:

```
(shell-command (format "echo -ne '\\033]12;red\\007' > /proc/%d/fd/1" (emacs-pid)))
```

It works (at least on Linux) by directly sending the ANSI escape sequence to the terminal (which is accessed through the `/proc/PID` pseudo-filesystem). I don't find this solution more elegant than the previous one, but at least it doesn't make the screen flicker.

Comment: This seems to work, the screen flickering is a bit annoying but there might not be a better way. If someone could come up with a better way that would be great.

Comment: Even if it's not "elegant" it works! Thanks so much for this solution!